# How can I get password of logged in user in Dynamics CRM on prem?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I know how to grab guid and User Name of current logged in user in Dynamics CRM 2016 on prem. But I also need to grab the password for some business reason and pass it to another application for managing documents of the user.

What I have searched I find only to get the id and user name of the user but nothing find about the password of the user. I need to know how can I get the password of the current logged in user. Any idea/suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: you can't get the password, for obvious security reasons

Comment: This is the purpose of ADFS...

Answer (score 2):

You can't - unless the user gives it to you.

Passwords are handled by the authentication layer (Windows Integrated or ADFS) and CRM has no knowledge of the user's password. I do not believe Active Directory (or any other LDAP service on which ADFS might use) would allow you to read a user password.

In Server Side Sync a user may provide their password to CRM for Exchange authentication ***BUT*** that password cannot be read by anything other than the CRM platform (and they are encrypted in SQL.) You will not be able to read that password using code or SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe CRM On-Premise utilizes Active Directory. AD passwords are stored using non-reversible encryption, so you wont be able to get that in a readable format unless you enable reversible encryption, which i'd not advise doing for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps mentioned to set up single sign on for sharepoint integration, this might help your cause.

Reference : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19662/how-to-set-up-single-sign-on-for-sharepoint-integration-in-crm-2011